# System Account Access to Domain Share

Tags: permissions, startup-scripts, shares

Good morning.

I'm trying to create a PowerShell startup script via Group Policy. I set the group policy and directed it to the location of the script.

\ \server\c$\share\script.ps1

After applying the GPO to the OU I want it to target for testing, I go a gpupdate\force on the test mule and this is what I get in the event viewer:

Event ID: 1130
Details:
ErrorCode 267
ErrorDescription The directory name is invalid.
GPOScriptCommandString \ \server\c$\share\script.ps1

On the domain share permissions I have:

COMPUTER$ read/write
Domain Computers read/write
Everyone read/write

On the script, I have the following NTFS permissions

Everyone - full control
COMPUTER$ - full control
Domain Computers (domain\domain computers) - full control
Administrators (domain\administrators) - full control

I've been bashing my head against the keyboard for hours. What am I doing wrong?

Server is 2016, test mule is Windows 10 Pro w/1709.

Answer (score 1):

C$ in path is Admin share so only Admins can access.
Instead share the Share folder as \Server\Share and set Security/Share permissions there to allow Domain Computers to access.